# Add New Domain in Windows Exchange Server 2013 With PHP

Tags: php, api, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-server-2013

I am using windows exchange server 2013 on windows server 2012.I am using PHP api reference: [PHP Exchange Web Services](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews)

My project requirement is: register domain/email online with PHP api verify domain if exists then register a new domain/email.

i have add new domain in UPN and its shows new domain in list of new mailboxes.

my query is

1. **how to add new domain with PHP api?**
2. **which domain is required in exchange server 2013? Active directory domain or accepted domains?**

Comment: domain? windows domain, or DNS domain?

Comment: DNS domain like @abc.com and can register new domain xyz.com for new mailboxes

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest against using that library. It's old and unmaintained, as well as hard to use. I maintain my own fork here https://github.com/garethp/php-ews. Secondly, those aren't the docs you want to be looking at, no matter what library you use. You want to look at the exchange documents directly. Here is the documentation for EWS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204119(v=exchg.150).aspx Honestly? I'm not sure if you can do what you want to do, that's where to start if you want to find out